# Divide all rows in a pandas dataframe by a specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
   Sample_name  C14-Cer_mean  C16-Cer_mean  C18-Cer_mean  C18:1-Cer_mean 
0          1 1      0.124749      0.285659     35.302029        8.173144   
1         1 10      0.332976      0.656197     39.220933        6.446620   
2         1 13      0.227423      0.272440     26.866943        5.763723   
3         1 14      0.128359      0.604903     29.848169        6.801633   
4          1 5      0.204000      0.242652     21.354158        4.637632   
5          1 6      0.122697      0.412868     25.168258        5.866785   
6          1 9      0.161679      0.569781     28.707720        6.525267   
7        Blank      0.408713      0.526573      0.531430        0.111025
```

I want to get a dataframe where values in all rows have been divided by the values in the row with Sample_name "Blank" (normalizing to sample "Blank"). How can I achieve this in pandas?

Comment: I think this should work: `df.loc[:,'C14-Cer_mean':].div(df.iloc[-1]['C14-Cer_mean':])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all the rows and slice the df using `loc` and then call [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and pass the last row using `iloc[-1]`:

```
In [58]:
df.loc[:,'C14-Cer_mean':] = df.loc[:,'C14-Cer_mean':].div(df.iloc[-1]['C14-Cer_mean':])
df

Out[58]:
      Sample_name C14-Cer_mean C16-Cer_mean C18-Cer_mean C18:1-Cer_mean
index                                                                  
0             1 1     0.305224     0.542487      66.4284        73.6153
1            1 10     0.814694      1.24617      73.8026        58.0646
2            1 13     0.556437     0.517383      50.5559        51.9137
3            1 14     0.314057      1.14875      56.1658        61.2622
4             1 5     0.499128     0.460814      40.1824        41.7711
5             1 6     0.300203     0.784066      47.3595         52.842
6             1 9     0.395581      1.08206      54.0198         58.773
7           Blank            1            1            1              1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[:,'C14-Cer_mean':] = df.loc[:,'C14-Cer_mean':].div(df.iloc[-1]['C14-Cer_mean':])

  Sample_name C14-Cer_mean C16-Cer_mean C18-Cer_mean C18:1-Cer_mean
0         1 1     0.305224     0.542487      66.4284        73.6153
1        1 10     0.814694      1.24617      73.8026        58.0646
2        1 13     0.556437     0.517383      50.5559        51.9137
3        1 14     0.314057      1.14875      56.1658        61.2622
4         1 5     0.499128     0.460814      40.1824        41.7711
5         1 6     0.300203     0.784066      47.3595         52.842
6         1 9     0.395581      1.08206      54.0198         58.773
7       Blank            1            1            1              1
```