# Conditionally changing value in a cell based on value in another cell Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a condition for changing the values of cells based on the value of another cell in the same column. The data frame reads as below:

```
    Sample_name  C14-Cer_mean  C16-Cer_mean  C18-Cer_mean  C18:1-Cer_mean 
0          1 1      0.124749      0.285659     35.302029        8.173144   
1         1 10      0.332976      0.656197     39.220933        6.446620   
2         1 13      0.227423      0.272440     26.866943        5.763723   
3         1 14      0.128359      0.604903     29.848169        6.801633   
4          1 5      0.204000      0.242652     21.354158        4.637632   
5          1 6      0.122697      0.412868     25.168258        5.866785   
6          1 9      0.161679      0.569781     28.707720        6.525267   
7        Blank      0.408713      0.526573      0.531430        0.111025
```

I want to check if the values in different rows (Sample_name) for columns C14-Cer_mean  C16-Cer_mean  C18-Cer_mean  C18:1-Cer_mean are lower than 2x the value of corresponding "Blank" and if they are - change them to 0. What'd be the best way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: In your sample df, none of the rows meet your conditions so it's a bit of a moot point

Comment: What is your expected outcome and what have you tried? [ask]

Comment: Also this question is not much different from one of your older questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820910/divide-all-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-specific-row

Comment: @EdChum I am not sure if I explained it clearly. For Sample_name "1 14", C14-Cer_mean is 0.20400, so this will be lower than 2*0.408713 and therefore changed to 0.00. While for the same Sample_name, C18-Cer_mean is 29.848169, which is greater than 2 times it's corresponding Blank (2*0.531430) and would be retained as is.