# How can I divide an entire dataframe by certain rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below, except much longer. Ultimately, `Var`, `Type`, and `Level`, when combined, represent unique entries.  I want to divide the unexposed entries against the other entries in the dataframe, according to the appropriate grouping (e.g., 'Any-All Exposed' would be divided by 'Any All Unexposed', whereas 'Any Existing Exposed' would be divided by 'Any Existing Unexposed.'

```
Var   Type      Level           Metric1 Metric2 Metric3
Any   All       Unexposed        34842  30783   -12
Any   All       Exposed          54167  54247   0.15
Any   All       LowExposure      20236  20311   0.37
Any   All       MediumExposure   15254  15388   0.87
Any   All       HighExposure     18677  18548   0.7
Any   New       Unexposed        0      23785   0
Any   New       Exposed          0      43030   0
Any   New       LowExposure      0      16356   0
Any   New       MediumExposure   0      12213   0
Any   New       HighExposure     0      14461   0
Any   Existing  Unexposed       34843   6998    -80
Any   Existing  Exposed         54167   11217   -80
Any   Existing  LowExposure     20236   3955    -81
Any   Existing  MediumExposure  15254   3175    -79
Any   Existing  HighExposure    18677   4087    -78
```

The most straightforward way to do this, I think, would be creating a mulitindex, but I've tried a variety of methods to no avail (normally, receiving an error that it can't divide on a non-unique index).

An expected result would be something like, where in every row is divided by the Unexposed row according to the var and type values.

```
Var   Type      Level           Metric1 Metric2 Metric3  MP1  MP2     MP3
Any   All       Unexposed        34842  30783   -12      1.00  1.00   1.00
Any   All       Exposed          54167  54247   0.15     1.55  1.76  -0.01
Any   All       LowExposure      20236  20311   0.37     0.58  0.66  -0.03
Any   All       MediumExposure   15254  15388   0.87     0.44  0.50  -0.07
Any   All       HighExposure     18677  18548   0.7      0.54  0.60  -0.06
Any   New       Unexposed        0      23785   0        0.00  1.00   0.00
Any   New       Exposed          0      43030   0        0.00  1.81   0.00
Any   New       LowExposure      0      16356   0        0.00  0.69   0.00
Any   New       MediumExposure   0      12213   0        0.00  0.51   0.00
Any   New       HighExposure     0      14461   0        0.00  0.61   0.00
Any   Existing  Unexposed       34843   6998    -80      1.00  1.00   1.00
Any   Existing  Exposed         54167   11217   -80      1.55  1.60   1.00
Any   Existing  LowExposure     20236   3955    -81      0.58  0.57   1.01
Any   Existing  MediumExposure  15254   3175    -79      0.44  0.45   0.99
Any   Existing  HighExposure    18677   4087    -78      0.54  0.58   0.98
```

Comment: [I think this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820910/divide-all-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-specific-row)

Comment: I don't think that will quite work; my dataframe is -much- larger than what I posted, so just grabbing one row doesn't work.  There are several potential values in each column, so tons of different combinations, and the values may differ depending on the dataset I load.  I'm looking for something that can flexibly take into consideration all of the different permutations.

Comment: I am not following, could you show what would be an expected result for this toy example?

Answer (score 1):

To divide every row in each `Var`/`Type` grouping by a specific `Level`, use `groupby` and `divide`.

For example, to divide by `Unexposed`, as in your example output:

```
def divide_by(g, denom_lvl):
    cols = ["Metric1", "Metric2", "Metric3"]
    num = g[cols]
    denom = g.loc[g.Level==denom_lvl, cols].iloc[0]
    return num.divide(denom).fillna(0).round(2)

df.groupby(['Var','Type']).apply(divide_by, denom_lvl='Unexposed')
```

Output:

```
    Metric1  Metric2  Metric3
0      1.00     1.00     1.00
1      1.55     1.76    -0.01
2      0.58     0.66    -0.03
3      0.44     0.50    -0.07
4      0.54     0.60    -0.06
5      0.00     1.00     0.00
6      0.00     1.81     0.00
7      0.00     0.69     0.00
8      0.00     0.51     0.00
9      0.00     0.61     0.00
10     1.00     1.00     1.00
11     1.55     1.60     1.00
12     0.58     0.57     1.01
13     0.44     0.45     0.99
14     0.54     0.58     0.98
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i got it correctly. Would sth like this do the trick?
You can parse all unique combinations and perform the division.

```
var_col= df['Var'].unique()
type_col= df['Type'].unique()

for i in var_col:
   for j in type_col:
      result= df[df['Var']==i][df['Type']==j][df['Level']=='Exposed'] / df[df['Var']==i][df['Type']==j][df['Level']=='Unexposed']
      ...
```